# Doubt in comma placement

Tags: punctuation

I need your help in understanding a concept:
I have a doubt. Does two two sentence imply same thing or they differ in meaning ??
I will stay at home, if you finish your work on time.
I will stay at home, if, you finish your work on time

Comment: It's not really anything to do with "comma placement" (the comma is effectively optional in both versions). It's just a matter of whether the "adverbial conditional" element is "fronted" or left in its more likely "trailing" position (but this doesn't change the intended sense, so far as I can see).

Answer (score 1):

You can visit Oxford University online for a comprehensive overview on the use of "if" and where to place the comma with "if" as a conjunction. Visit: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/if_1

Your question, "Does two two sentence imply same thing or they differ in meaning ??"

The correct answer is, as Oxford University (www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com) states, "if" is... "used to say that one thing can, will or might happen or be true, depending on another thing happening or being true..."

"If" is a common subordinating conjunction that describes a "condition" much like "if only" or "provided" "since" "unless," etc.  Subordinating conjunctions convey their meaning without help from other function words, such as the coordinating conjunctions [and, but, for, and so.) //Ref: Little Brown Handbook, 10th Ed. Pg. 251  Pearson Education, Inc (2010).

---

In your provided sentence, "if" is used to introduce a contrast. The comma is placed only once at the end of the word before "if,' not after "if."  Therefore, the correct answer to your question is:

I will stay at home, if you finish your work on time.

---

The subordinating conjunction can also be placed at the beginning of the sentence.

"If you finish your work on time, I will stay at home."

The meaning is the same.  However, the emphasis on "condition" is changed in these two examples.  The 1st sentence condition and emphasis is emphatic - "if you finish your work on time." In the 2nd sentence, the condition remains the same, but emphasis is  on "I will stay home," if the condition is met.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

The first one is correct. There's a simple trick; Suppose that the commas you put are fullstops, check the sentence you wrote and if it makes sense alone its correct (e.g 'I will stay at home'. It makes sense by itself doesn't it?)

For further questions feel free to ask me.